# How do I execute a bash script onHover over the iTerm2 window?

Tags: python, shellexecute, onhover

Is there a way to configure iTerm2 (or a pyqt5 button) to execute a bash script `onHover`?

The behavior I'm looking for is to configure iTerm's (split window) to execute a bash script (ideally a python script) when I select it or when I hover over it?

Comment: That's purely an iTerm question -- nothing either python or bash has built in will help with this. Perhaps [apple.se] might be a more appropriate forum?

Comment: Not necessarily, consider being able to configure any Terminal (Xterm, etc) to execute a script when 1) you configure it to do something like `python mypython.py` & 2) you enable the term to run the script when you hover over it. In my case I could configure a pyQt pushbutton to react when hoverOver (I think), but don't want to go there if a terminal can be configured to do that. Two other less elegant options are i) cron job to run the script every 2 mins or ii) configure a sockets to do something similar.

Comment: "Considering" the goal doesn't change the truth of my initial statement: Nothing Python or Bash has built in will help with this. If your terminal has support for triggers, that's a question about that terminal. If you're asking for someone to recommend a terminal that *does* support triggers, that's a software recommendation request and off-topic here.